# Problems with Primefaces editor calendar galleria etc

Tags: primefaces, editor

I've just started using primefaces 3.5 and I'm dealing with a weird problem.
1. editor doesn't show up on the page
2. galleria only shows the images in a list
3.popups don't work at all
4. calendar appears as a text field

**does anybody know what could have caused this problem?** *I'm not getting any errors and other stuff like p:media work just fine.*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>First JSF</title>
</head>
<p:editor></p:editor>
</html>
```

Comment: The same thing happening with the live demo available in PF website or it happening when you try to run your demo application?

Comment: no it just happens when I run my application. The generated script writing a simple editor in my application is this: <div id="editor" style="visibility:hidden"><textarea id="editor_input" name="editor_input"></textarea></div><script id="editor_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Editor','widget_editor',{id:'editor'},'editor');});</script> which I don't see any problems in it!

Comment: Can you post your JSf page code?

Comment: Please edit your post rather than adding in comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Finally I solved the problem.
Just simply used `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` tag that I'd used before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add below line in your JSF page

```
<f:view contentType="text/html"/>
```

Comment: are you using any jquery outside PF?

Comment: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6831 see this are you getting issue smething like this

Comment: thank you, but I've seen that before and tried that but it didn't work. It's a really weird problem!